# Segmentation fault on linked list

Tags: c

So, i have this funtions in my imprimeL.c file that prints every intenger of l(*LInt), it shows seg fault on

```
(l -> prox) -> valor = 2 
(l -> prox) -> prox = NULL;
```

My imprimeL funtion is well defined and my struct lligada is:

```
typedef struct lligada {

    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;

} *LInt;

void imprimeL(LInt l){

    LInt aux;

    while(l != NULL){

        printf("%d\n", l-> valor);
        aux = l-> prox;
        free(l);
        aux = NULL;
        l = aux;
    }

}

int main(){

    LInt l = malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
    l -> valor = 1;
    (l -> prox) -> valor = 2;
    (l -> prox) -> prox = NULL;

    imprimeL(l);

    printf("Ola\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So.. where `(l -> prox)` is pointing to (I am referring to the third line of `main`..)?

Comment: You want to allocate memory to `l->prox`

Comment: @EugeneSh. it is pointed to the next struct lligada

Comment: @Cid by allocating memory to l, I'm alocating memory to l->prox.

Comment: Where in your code?

Comment: What next struct if you haven't allocated any except `l`?  Also you have never assigned anything to it.

Comment: @LeonardoMaia right after your `malloc`, `l->prox` points nowhere.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So how do i do it to create a struct lligada ?

Comment: `malloc` does not initialize memory, so `l->prox` will have an invalid pointer value until you change the pointer to point somewhere meaningful, probably to another `malloc`ed `struct lliigada`.

Comment: You've already `malloc`ed storage for one `struct lligada` so it shouldn't be hard to work out how to `malloc` storage for another one. To save us all from banging our heads against the wall in frustration, I'll show you how to do it explicitly: `l->prox = malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you, i got it guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct lligada {    
  int valor;
  struct lligada *prox;    
} *LInt;

void imprimeL(LInt l) {    
  LInt aux;

  while (l != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", l->valor);
    aux = l->prox;
    free(l);
    l = aux;
  }    
}

int main() {    
  LInt l = malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
  l->valor = 1;

  LInt l1 = malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
  l->prox = l1;

  l1->valor = 2;
  l1->prox = NULL;

  imprimeL(l);

  printf("Ola\n");
  return 0;
}
```

There is also a bug in your `imprimeL` function.

The next step for you is to create the linked list dynamically with a loop.

Comment: @LeonardoMaia compare your version with mine.It shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: @LeonardoMaia your version displays and frees only the first element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

A segmentation fault happens when you access a memory address that you do not have access to. In your case when you allocate memory for l, your lligada data structure is below:

```
int valor                -> some garbage value
struct lligada *prox;    -> NULL pointer
```

So then when you access l->prox ->prox you are trying to access a null pointer which causes a seg fault.

To avoid that, you can allocate memory for prox before accessing its elements.